# How do I prevent Google from killing access to sister/brother sites?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google, google-translate

My free portfolio on google.com allows me partial functionality on some accounts.

For instance:

- It allows me to use the Google Mail account almost without a hitch (at times Hangouts will simply keep trying to connect even though mail are sent, and the reply received);
- Any attempt to log on directly to the Google Drive has the browser refresh recurrently until the browser is closed;
- I may log on into the translate.google.com. Yet my attempt to navigate to any of the relevant links (Translator toolkit, Website Translator, Global Market Finder) immediately demands that I log on again, taking me to the `/translate_t` page from where my attempt to navigate to any of and so on ad infinitum!

My environment is as follows:

- OS: Windows 7
- Browser: IE 10

Here's what I hope to find out:

- Is this a common problem with the free Google portfolio?
- How do I prevent Google from killing my access to sister/brother sites?

Comment: I certainly don't have any problems like you describe. I don't know that we can help, though. The first thing I would try is a different browser. (Chrome, as you might expect, works really well with Google apps.) If that doesn't help, then there's probably something wonky with your network.

Comment: Another issue might be cookies. If your browser is set up to delete cookies (or if you're using a tool to do the same) Google is going to forget who you are and prompt you to log in.

Comment: Hm. IE is in private mode by default on this box - but all it does in prompt whether I want to run xyz cookie from the site - and I usually accept. I tried Tor last night - same issues. One more thing ... not about Google though - I'm unable to edit posts to FB. It's like using the old terminal on unix boxes - backspace doesn't work, delete doesn't work! I usually end up throwing my hands up, reloading the page, and entering the post all over again! What could be wrong with the network? If you could drop a hint, perhaps I could ask over in serverfault, or superuser ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Some Google services use top country domains as the default for users out of the US while others don't. Some of these pages don't share the sign in status (use different cookies) with pages with different top country domain.

I.E. 
I'm in Mexico:
- when I follow a link to any Blogger article, the URL's domain changes to blospot.com.mx.
- when I go to www.google.es, usually the sign in button is displayed.